# Crash inside GoogleSignInAccount in latest PlayServices 8.3

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

The latest release on play services (8.3) has an issue related to GoogleSignInAccount.

We received a crash generated from it. Here it is the stacktrace.

```
Android: 4.4.4
Manufacturer: Sony
Model: D5503
Date: Thu Nov 12 16:36:06 GMT-08:00 2015

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=40962, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.spreaker.android/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3498)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1882)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.zzms(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.zzmx(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzn.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzn.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3451)
    ... 11 more
```

Checking the app logs on our side, could be related to some connectivity issue but I could be wrong.

Any help with this is appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:
Upon request, this is how we build the GoogleApiClient (and required options)

```
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder gsoBuilder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(
                    new Scope("profile"),
                    new Scope("email"),
                    new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
            )
            .requestProfile()
            .requestServerAuthCode(this._config.getGoogleClientId(), true);

    this._googleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new OnConnectionErrorListener())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gsoBuilder.build())
            .build();
```

Comment: Google made [improvements to signin in 8.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/11/improvements-to-sign-in-with-google.html), so maybe you have to make some updates/changes.

Comment: Yes, and we changed everything to do thing properly with it. We don't do anything special here. We just wait for the google account returned by the new api but it crashes instead of giving us the account. There is a bug inside their new API I think.

Comment: I see the same crash on 8.3, no solution yet.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this yet?

Comment: No, it depends on the implementation of Play Services. I hope Google will see this question and take it as an reported issue.

Comment: Could you post your code showing how you build your GoogleSignInOptions and GoogleApiClient?

Comment: Added code for building GoogleSignInOption and GoogleApiClient as suggested by @StevenSoneff

Comment: Issue reported here [Crash using new Google Signing 8.3](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1273)

Comment: Can folks here comment on: a) Is it stable repro b) does change account help? c) does change device help? device type / OS version to repro? And a full bug report will also help. Thanks,

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318888/google-sign-in-for-android

Comment: this problem still exist even for version 9.0.0

Comment: haha I got this in 19.0.0 , can't find anywhere why one user with Nexus 5X on Android 8.1.0 get's this crash