# Google SIgn-In for android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-services, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I tried the google developer documentation and tried sign-in for my app.
The code is copied from the git with added codes from the [documentation.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14071857/) 
and defined in *LoginActivity* as

```
Public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "* * SignIn * *";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
Bundle userData = new Bundle();
Intent newIntent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
   findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]

    // [START customize_button]
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // [END customize_button]
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {

        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        userData.putString("Username", acct.getDisplayName());
        userData.putString("Email",acct.getEmail());
        newIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        newIntent.putExtras(userData);
        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        userData.putString("Username", "Anonymous");
        userData.putString("Email","www.example.com");
        newIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        newIntent.putExtras(userData);
        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]





@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;

    }
}
```

}

But I get following error [log.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14071857/) 
as

```
12-16 23:02:44.074 5545-5545/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=40962, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} 
                                                                     to activity {com.example.www.newapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: 
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
```

My *MainActivity* code is as

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(user);//Username recieved through intent
}}
```

While running it in emulator it shows update your play service, is it a problem?

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: @qbix log :: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14071857/

Comment: A very similar stack trace is posted at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689689/crash-inside-googlesigninaccount-in-latest-playservices-8-3). No solution there but comments may be helpful.  FWIW--I downloaded and built the [demo app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) and ran it without problem using Play Service 8.3.0 on a KitKat device.

Comment: yeah it worked in the hardware :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error occurred only in emulator in when compiling with new play service 8.3
While testing in actual hardware doesn't show any problem. It is due to the mismatch in the play service versions in emulator and the API.
Hope they upgrade the Google API SDK with latest play service and release some notice about it.