# Alternative Google Sign-In in android

Tags: android, github, google-api-client, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I was trying for Android Sign-In following the [documents](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) and the code in [Git](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L51-L55). But I get [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34318888/5383826),

```
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.www.newapp, PID: 3098
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=40962, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.www.newapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1896)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.zzms(Unknown Source)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.zzmx(Unknown Source)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzn.zza(Unknown Source)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzn.zzb(Unknown Source)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zza(Unknown Source)
12-17 13:55:43.287 3098-3098/com.example.www.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
```

so is there an alternative way I could use Google Sign-In in my android app.
Help appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem. I guess you use the emulator? And you don't have the latest play services version since it cannot been updated?

Comment: @rekire YES, I am banging my head against the laptop now.

Comment: Well this might explain it, but this is still no solution... I tested my code on real hardware there it works fine, but it is still a valid case that a user has not installed the latest play services.

Comment: @rekire thanks, I hope they update the play services in SDK soon